# Jenkins - reserve build for specific job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have few jenkins jobs which trigger acceptance test. At this moment AT are configured to run 5 concurrent builds:

```
  throttleJobProperty(
            maxConcurrentPerNode: 0,
            maxConcurrentTotal: 5,
            paramsToUseForLimit: '',
            throttleEnabled: true,
            throttleOption: 'project'
        )
```

I would like to always have 1 build reserved for specific downstream trigger. So, if job2/job3/job4/jobN trigger AT, I want to be able to run AT triggered via job1 without waiting in queue. Is this somehow possible? If not, can similar configuration be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins, the throttleJobProperty that you have configured is used to limit the number of concurrent builds for a specific job. However, it doesn't provide a direct way to reserve a slot for a specific downstream trigger.

Here's a simplified example using a Scripted Pipeline:

```
if (currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(hudson.model.Cause$UpstreamCause)) {
    def upstreamCause = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(hudson.model.Cause$UpstreamCause)
    def upstreamJobName = upstreamCause.upstreamProject

    if (upstreamJobName == 'job1') {
        // Don't apply throttling for job1
    } else {
        throttleJobProperty(
            maxConcurrentPerNode: 0,
            maxConcurrentTotal: 5,
            paramsToUseForLimit: '',
            throttleEnabled: true,
            throttleOption: 'project'
        )
    }
}

// Rest of your pipeline steps for acceptance tests
```

Comment: Okey, so not sure if throtlling is what I'm looking for, but I will test it tomorrow.

Comment: In the above answer, seems like you would set maxConcurrentTotal: 4 to avoid potentially starting a 6th concurrent job when job1 comes along and 5 jobs are already running.